# WideImage can't save to file for unknown reason and can't output due to headers issue

Tags: php, image

When I try to have the WideImage create the thumnail (after checking if it exists):

```
    public function printSummaryArticle($article, $copy) {
    // create a thumbnail for the image as per the row data if one does not exist
    if (!file_exists('/images/articles/thumbs/th_' . $article['image'])) {
        $image_handle = imagecreatefromjpeg(Config::getAbsPath() . '/images/articles/' . $article['image']);
        // WideImage plugin
        WideImage::load($image_handle)->resize(300, 200)->saveToFile(Config::getAbsPath() . '/images/articles/thumbs/th_' . $article['image']);
    }
    // echo the thumbnail just created
    echo
        '<div class="summary_article"><img src="/images/articles/thumbs/th_'
        . $article['image']
        . '">';
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: imagejpeg(/images/articles/thumbs/th_037.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/obmonco1/public_html/gulfinsight/lib/omc_frmwrk/plugins/WideImage/Mapper/JPEG.php on line 39

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'WideImage_UnknownErrorWhileMappingException' with message 'WideImage_Mapper_JPEG returned an invalid result while saving to /images/articles/thumbs/th_037.jpg' in /home2/obmonco1/public_html/gulfinsight/lib/omc_frmwrk/plugins/WideImage/Image.php:164 Stack trace: #0 /home2/obmonco1/public_html/gulfinsight/lib/omc_frmwrk/bespoke/DisplayEngine.php(181): WideImage_Image->saveToFile('/images/article...') #1 /home2/obmonco1/public_html/gulfinsight/lib/omc_frmwrk/bespoke/PageTemplate.php(70): DisplayEngine->printSummaryArticle(Array, Object(GetCopy)) #2 /home2/obmonco1/public_html/gulfinsight/index.php(100): PageTemplate->homePage() #3 {main} thrown in /home2/obmonco1/public_html/gulfinsight/lib/omc_frmwrk/plugins/WideImage/Image.php on line 164
```

I gotta use absolute paths, but it doesn't work with or without the 'root' portion of the path ( *Config::getAbsPath()* ).
I have also tried accessing the image directly instead of creating an image handler first, as you see above.

When I try to output the image directly using the output method:

```
    public function printSummaryArticle($article, $copy) {
    // create a thumbnail for the image as per the row data if one does not exist
    if (!file_exists('/images/articles/thumbs/th_' . $article['image'])) {
        $image_handle = imagecreatefromjpeg(Config::getAbsPath() . '/images/articles/' . $article['image']);
        // WideImage plugin
        WideImage::load($image_handle)->resize(300, 200)->output('jpeg');
    }
    // echo the thumbnail just created
    echo
        '<div class="summary_article"><img src="/images/articles/thumbs/th_'
        . $article['image']
        . '">';
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\Open Media Collective\Projects\Gulf Insight\web\publish\lib\omc_frmwrk\bespoke\DisplayEngine.php:130) in D:\Open Media Collective\Projects\Gulf Insight\web\publish\lib\omc_frmwrk\plugins\WideImage\Image.php on line 198
```

*Which is followed by the binary data of the image*

I have opened and checked every php file I have to look for whitespace before and after the opening-closing php tags.. and I would rather not use output buffer.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I have set permissions to 777 for the images, articles, and thumbs folders. Same error.

REQUESTED ADDITION:

"WideImage/Mapper/JPEG.php on line 39"

```
    return imagejpeg($handle, $uri, $quality);
```

I shouldn't have to touch the lib though. I tried giving absolute paths to the file, localhost, and remote host. Makes no difference. I know the path to the image is correct. Which is why the error makes no sense.

Comment: Please show us where the line numbers appearing in your errors are in the code. First error indicates the path to the file is incorrect...

Comment: I added the information you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

the offending line was this:

```
WideImage::load($image_handle)->resize(300, 200)->saveToFile('/images/articles/thumbs/th_' . $article['image']);
```

I had to use the full path (including root: Config::getAbsPath()) even here, not just in the image handler.